# UIViewcontroller image dimensions

Tags: ios

I wanted to display a png image in the center of my main view controller. Do I have to use a UIImageView or just add the image to the view itself?. I don't want to cover the whole view but just in the center with a fairly large image. What would be the ideal dimensions of the image be for all iOS devices (supporting iOS 6.0 and above)?.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use UIImageView like you said. There are ways of manipulating other classes to display images, but it's more code overall and more confusing to look at. As for the ideal dimensions, it depends on the aspect ratio of your image and the rest of your view.

Comment: Thanks. If the png image size is 300x264, what would be the ideal scaled down versions for non-retina and retina based iPad and iPhone devices?